# PyOMO: Variable with binary domain is being optimized to float values b/w 0 and 1

Tags: python, pyomo

I am currently trying to optimize my cost equation using few NonNegativeReal Variables and Few Binary Variables using Xpress Solver. 
I have following issue:

1. The solver returns float values in b/w 0 and 1 whereas expected output is 0 or 1.
2. I assume that something is wrong while declaring the variable. Can somebody point out the error?

## Variable definition

```
M.U1=Var(M.T, domain=Boolean, bounds=(0,1), initialize=1)
M.U2=Var(M.T, domain=Boolean, bounds=(0,1), initialize=1)
M.U3=Var(M.T, domain=Boolean, bounds=(0,1), initialize=1)
M.U4=Var(M.T, domain=Boolean, bounds=(0,1), initialize=1)
```

## Constraints

```
M.aL=Constraint(expr=M.a[t]>=constraint_data['Minimum Stable Output - Pmin (MW)'][0]*M.U1[t])
M.aU=Constraint(expr=M.a[t]<=constraint_data['Maximum Stable Output - Pmax (MW)'][0]*M.U1[t])
M.bL=Constraint(expr=M.b[t]>=constraint_data['Minimum Stable Output - Pmin (MW)'][1]*M.U2[t])
M.bU=Constraint(expr=M.b[t]<=constraint_data['Maximum Stable Output - Pmax (MW)'][1]*M.U2[t])
M.cL=Constraint(expr=M.c[t]>=constraint_data['Minimum Stable Output - Pmin (MW)'][2]*M.U3[t])
M.cU=Constraint(expr=M.c[t]<=constraint_data['Maximum Stable Output - Pmax (MW)'][2]*M.U3[t])
M.dL=Constraint(expr=M.d[t]>=constraint_data['Minimum Stable Output - Pmin (MW)'][3]*M.U4[t])
M.dU=Constraint(expr=M.d[t]<=constraint_data['Maximum Stable Output - Pmax (MW)'][3]*M.U4[t])

M.C1=Constraint(expr=(M.a[t]+M.b[t]+M.c[t]+M.d[t])==data['Utility Load (MW)'][t])
```

## Objective Function

```
 expression1=M.U1[t]*M.a[t]*cost_data['Price ($/MWh)'][0]+M.U2[t]*M.b[t]*cost_data['Price ($/MWh)'] [1]+M.U3[t]*M.c[t]*cost_data['Price ($/MWh)'][1]+M.U4[t]*M.d[t]*cost_data['Price ($/MWh)'][2]
 M.obj = Objective(expr=expression1 ,sense= minimize)
```

## Optimization

```
optimizer=SolverFactory('xpress')
optimizer.solve(M)
```

Comment: Can you show the solver log?

Comment: Changing the solver to 'amplxpress' just solved my problem. I think 'xpress' solver is unable to handle binary variable.